# PHP Image manipulation moire effect

Tags: php, image

I am making a site where people can upload their own background images. One of the things users really having a problem understanding is image sizes and resolution. If I say 'Make sure your background is at least 1080x1920 pixels (Full HiDef)' I am guessing a good 70% of people will not know what this means or how to do it.

So what I would like to do is enlarge small images in a nicer way than just making them blurry. What I would like to do is something like this:-
http://nanotux.com/plugins/fullscreenr/index.html
where basically every other dot is a black pixel, that way small images will be twice the size when they are stretched to 1080x1920 and generally look better.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with PHP's image functions?
(as an aside does anyone know what this type of effect should be called? Moire? would that be accurate?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you well, you want to set every second pixel in `x` and `y` dimensions to black on the stretched image?

This should do the trick (not tested, I relied on PHP documentation).

```php
   $initialImage = ... // handle to the image

   $srcWidth = imagesx($initialImage);
   $srcHeight = imagesy($initialImage);
   $maxX = 1920;
   $maxY = 1080;

   $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($max_x, $max_y);
   imagecopyresampled ($newImage, $initialImage, 0,0,0,0, $maxX, $maxY, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

   $BLACK = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
   for($x=0; $x+=2; $x<$max_x){
      for($y=0; $y+=2; $y<$max_y){
         imagesetpixel($newImage, $x, $y, $BLACK);
      }
   }
```

Documentation: [imagesetpixel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php), [imagecolorallocate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php), [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php),
[imagecreatetruecolor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php).

Read PHP documentation and examples there. Remember to use `imagecopyresampled` instead of `imagecopyresized` to have better quality.

Comment: Of course this is simplified version, this will always stretch the original to fit 1920x1080, you may want to do some cropping etc. to maintain the x:y ratio.

Comment: +1. You could just take my answer and integrate it into yours. It's ok to me!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, will try out and post back results

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal way would be to create a transparent raster (.png) "by hand" (i.e. create it programmatically as in jakub.gieryluk's solution), and overlay that, multiple times if needed, via `imagecopy()`.

Drawing pixel by pixel is painfully slow.

Comment: Yeah the idea is though to expand the image by making every other pixel black rather than just blowing it up and making it blurry and then adding a moire over the top of it. I am not sure if I understand you correctly but I think that doing it your way would mean blowing the original up to twice its size (and making it look rubbish) and then replacing every other (rubbish) pixel with a black one (or doing this in groups), where as if you do it the other way the image should retain more integrity... I think... will post results for comparison shortly :)

Comment: You should still use `imagecopyresampled` of course. Just not `imagesetpixel`. Not after you've got a sample grid say 100x100 wide to put on top of it repeatedly. My solution is not a complete alternative to the one above, it's just an optimization.